# Clustering data with temporal effect

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering, spatio-temporal

As an example of a dataframe, we could think a problem such as:

(my real table is much bigger and with a lot of ID_PRODUCTs and a lot of ID_CLASS_PRODUCTs)

| ID_CLIENT | DATE | ID_PRODUCT | ID_CLASS_PRODUCT | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nov/20 | 3 | A | 20 |
| 1 | Nov/20 | 2 | A | 100 |
| 1 | Dec/20 | 2 | A | 18 |
| 1 | Dec/20 | 3 | A | 100 |
| 2 | May/20 | 3 | A | 10 |
| 2 | Jul/20 | 3 | A | 10 |
| 2 | Aug/20 | 3 | A | 12 |
| 2 | Oct/20 | 3 | A | 10 |
| 2 | Nov/20 | 3 | A | 11 |
| 2 | Dec/20 | 3 | A | 09 |
| 2 | Aug/20 | 3 | A | 12 |
| 3 | Oct/20 | 5 | B | 10 |
| 3 | Nov/20 | 5 | B | 11 |
| 3 | Dec/20 | 5 | B | 09 |

So, we have different number of observations for each client, where each observation represents a Purchase of a Product from a specific client in a month of the year.

If my goal is to find a cluster for all active users at month Dec/20, would it make sense to include the past in an unsupervised model such K-means?

I'm a little confused since, first, we would have temporal autocorrelation of observations that are restricted to the same id_client and also because clustering would indicate a group for the client, on a date for a certain product.

Any suggestions on what changes to make in the data table if the objective is to indicate groupings for active customers in December 2020.